# Windows Phone - know when the screen is on

Tags: windows-phone, lockscreen

I'm working on an app that changes the lock screen background, and I would like to know when the user turns on his phone and looks at the lock screen.

The reason for my question is that if I know that the background has been watched, I will be able to replace the background.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you're describing. When your application isn't running, you have no information whichever about user's activity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. If your lockscreen is activated you cannot Access to App data, for security reason.

So, as KooKiz said there is no way to do that.